# How many database calls required for server side datatable

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, datatable, dao

This is actually strategic ans i am seeking for.
I am doing server side paging with the help of jquery datatable plugin.Every thing is i.e. parsing datatable info and using it.

TO get and send related datatable info I am calling database three times:

```
//1. To fetch the total count.
int total = genericDao.getTotalRecordCount(filteredCountQuery);//this query is like: select count(*) as count from table.
//2. To fetch filtered count in case of search.
if(!searchQuery.isEmpty()){
searchQuery = " AND " + searchQuery;
String filteredCountQuery = parsedDatatable.get("totalCount") + specialQuery+searchQuery;//this query is like: select count(*) as count from table where search_condition.
filteredCount = genericDao.getTotalRecordCount(filteredCountQuery);
}
//3. To get data.
String recordsQuery = specialQuery+searchQuery + parsedDatatable.get("records");
List<ObjectList> list = daoClass.findByWhere(recordsQuery);
```

My concerned is is it good way or some other way is there?

If any code clarification is required then inform.

I am using spring-mvc, jdbctemplate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many database calls required for one draw server side datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435606/how-many-database-calls-required-for-one-draw-server-side-datatable)

Comment: Please avoid posting [duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435606/how-many-database-calls-required-for-one-draw-server-side-datatable).

Comment: Actually I didnt get any ans or comment that why I posted as i thought ppl might not have seen as so many posts generates every secs.